# Data Entry to Table with Entry key issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I have created student data entry dialog using PyQt5 QTableWidget, QLineEdit, QComboBox.

Here is the PyQt5 code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog,
                               QApplication,
                               QGridLayout,
                               QPushButton,
                               QLabel,
                               QLineEdit,
                               QComboBox,
                               QTableWidget,
                               QTableWidgetItem,
                               QAbstractItemView)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MyWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Student Data Entry')

        grdLayout = QGridLayout()           

        self.lblStudentId = QLabel('Student Id')
        self.cboStudentId = QComboBox(self)
        self.cboStudentId.addItems(['1000','6001','5000','5002','9000','1004'])
        self.cboStudentId.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.lblStudentName = QLabel('Student name',self)
        self.ledStudentName = QLineEdit(self)
        
        self.lblAge = QLabel('Age',self)
        self.ledAge = QLineEdit(self)
        self.ledAge.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.ledAge.setPlaceholderText('0')

        self.lblAdd = QLabel('Add',self)
        self.btnAdd = QPushButton('Add',self)
        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.addFeeRow)        

        # student data table
        self.tblStudent = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tblStudent.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tblStudent.setShowGrid(True)
        self.tblStudent.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Student Id', 'Student name','Age'))
        self.tblStudent.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.tblStudent.setEditTriggers(QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tblStudent.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows) 
        self.tblStudent.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
        self.tblStudent.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.tblStudent.setColumnWidth(2, 25)         

        # Add Label, LineEdit and ComboBox
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.lblStudentId,0,0)
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.lblStudentName,0,1,1,2)
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.lblAge,0,3)
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.lblAdd,0,4)

        grdLayout.addWidget(self.cboStudentId,1,0)
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.ledStudentName,1,1,1,2)
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.ledAge,1,3)
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.btnAdd,1,4)
        
        # Add table
        grdLayout.addWidget(self.tblStudent,2,0,1,4)

        grdLayout.setColumnStretch(0,1)
        grdLayout.setColumnStretch(1,1)
        grdLayout.setColumnStretch(2,1)    

        self.setLayout(grdLayout)
        
    def addFeeRow(self):
        rowCount = self.tblStudent.rowCount()
        self.tblStudent.insertRow(rowCount)
        # insert into table
        self.tblStudent.setItem(rowCount,0, QTableWidgetItem(self.cboStudentId.currentText()))
        self.tblStudent.setItem(rowCount,1, QTableWidgetItem(self.ledStudentName.text()))
        self.tblStudent.setItem(rowCount,2, QTableWidgetItem(self.ledAge.text()))
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
```

[image]

My requirements are,

1. when user clicks **Add** QPushButton or Press Enter key when **Age** QLineEdit is focused, Data (student id, student name, and student age) should be entered into table. Data should be entered into the table when user presses Enter key in Age QLineEdit or Add QPushButton.
2. Also when user press **Enter key** in **Student Id** QComboBox, focus should move to **next widget (Student Name)**. When user presses **Enter key** in **Student Name** QLineEdit, focus should move to **next widget (Student Age)**

**In the current scenario**, when user presses Enter Key in any widgets like student id, student name, Data is entering into table, which I don't want. **Please provide the solution to restrict this behaviour.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue about the return key triggering from everywhere is that when using a QDialog and at least a button with the [`autoDefault()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) property set, that button's `clicked` signal is triggered whenever the return key is pressed.

In order to disable that, the following is required:

```
        self.btnAdd.setAutoDefault(False)
```

Since you also want to control the focus using that key, then you can implement the `keyPressEvent` instead, ensuring that it doesn't get processed in those situations (in this case, the `setAutoDefault` above is theoretically not necessary anymore):

```
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter):
            current = QApplication.focusWidget()
            if current == self.cboStudentId:
                self.ledStudentName.setFocus()
                return
            elif current == self.ledStudentName:
                self.ledAge.setFocus()
                return
            elif current == self.ledAge:
                self.addFeeRow()
                self.cboStudentId.setFocus()
                return
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Finally, if you want to also change the focus when the user presses enter on the popup of the combobox, an event filter must be used:

```
class MyWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.cboStudentId.view().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and 
            event.key() in (Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter)):
                self.ledStudentName.setFocus()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly. thanks a lot. 
Do I need to use self.btnAdd.setAutoDefault(True) in order to work Enter key with Button. 
If self.btnAdd.setAutoDefault(False), Enter key is not working with button. only mouse click is working.

What is the default value of autoDefault(). Is it True or False?

Comment: @RaviKannan Read the documentation (it's linked in the post), and you can obviously know that value *before* setting it just by calling `self.btnAdd.autoDefault()`. That said, I already wrote in the question: "in this case, the `setAutoDefault` above is theoretically not necessary anymore".

Comment: I understood. thanks for your timely help and support